# Detect URL and add anchor tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am parsing html using BeautifulSoup. Given following HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>An absolute URL: https://www.w3schools.com</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I wish to convert it to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">https://www.w3schools.com</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code written so far:

```
def detect_urls_and_update_target(self, root): //root is the soup object
        for tag in root.find_all(True):
            if tag.name == 'a':
                if not tag.has_attr('target'):
                    tag.attrs['target'] = '_blank'
            elif tag.string is not None:
                  for url in re.findall(self.url_regex, tag.string): //regex which detects URLS which works
                      new_tag = root.new_tag("a", href=url, target="_blank")
                      new_tag.string = url
                      tag.append(new_tag)
```

This adds the required anchor tag but I am not able to figure out how do I remove the original URL from the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use BeautifulSoup to reconstruct the parent contents as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>An absolute URL: https://www.w3schools.com</p>
        <p>Another link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413693/detect-url-and-add-anchor-tags-using-beautifulsoup%22</p>
        <div><div>some div</div>Hello world from https://www.google.com</div>
    </body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
re_url = re.compile(r'(http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+)')

for tag in soup.find_all(text=True):
    tags = []
    url = False

    for t in re_url.split(tag.string):
        if re_url.match(t):
            a = soup.new_tag("a", href=t, target='_blank')
            a.string = t
            tags.append(a)
            url = True
        else:
            tags.append(t)

    if url:
        for t in tags:
            tag.insert_before(t)
        tag.extract()

print(soup)    
print()
```

This would display the following output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">https://www.w3schools.com</a></p>
<p>Another link: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413693/detect-url-and-add-anchor-tags-using-beautifulsoup%22" target="_blank">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413693/detect-url-and-add-anchor-tags-using-beautifulsoup%22</a></p>
<div><div>some div</div>Hello world from <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">https://www.google.com</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works by first splitting any tags containing text using a regular expression to find any URL. For each entry, if it is a URL, replace it in the list with a new anchor tag. If no URLs are found, leave the tag alone. Next insert each list of updated tags before the existing tag and then remove the existing tag.

---

To skip over any URLs in the `DOCTYPE`, the `find_all()` could be altered as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Doctype

...

for tag in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: not isinstance(text, Doctype)):
```

Comment: Just realised, if the url is like "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413693/detect-url-and-add-anchor-tags-using-beautifulsoup" it strips of everything after the first forward slash

Comment: Spotting URLs in text with regex is often not perfect, I've used a different one which seems to improve matters.

Comment: It breaks for `<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body> <div><div>some div</div>Hello world from https://www.google.com</div> </body> </html>`

Comment: If the DOCTYPE tag is like
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` then the result is 
`html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "<a href="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" target="_blank">http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd</a>" `

How can I exclude DOCTYPE while iterating on all the tags?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` with a decorator to wrap any occurrences of a url in a tag body with provided parameters:

```
import re
def format_hrefs(tags=['p'], _target='blank', a_class=''):
   def outer(f):
     def format_url(url):
        _start = re.sub('https*://www\.[\w\W]+\.\w{3}', '{}', url)
        return _start.format(*['<a href="{}" _target="{}" class="{}">{}</a>'.format(i, _target, a_class, i) for i in re.findall('https*://www\.\w+\.\w{3}', url)])
     def wrapper():
        url = f()
        _format = re.sub('|'.join('(?<=\<'+i+'\>)[\w\W]+(?=\</'+i+'\>)' for i in tags), '{}', html)
        _text = re.findall('|'.join('(?<=\<'+i+'\>)[\w\W]+(?=\</'+i+'\>)' for i in tags), html)
        return _format.format(*[format_url(i) for i in _text])
     return wrapper
   return outer

@format_hrefs()
def get_html():
   content = """
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <body>
        <p>An absolute URL: https://www.w3schools.com</p>
      </body>
     </html>
    """
   return content

print(get_html())
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
   <p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" _target="blank" class="">https://www.w3schools.com</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am very new to python and having some difficulty following your solution, can you please explain how does it work?

Comment: Also, how does this impl ensures that if there is already an anchor tag, the href of that anchor tag is not wrapped by another anchor tag?